# Binding on a nested property without using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

How to make a binding on a nested target property, like `Shape.Stroke.Color` in WPF without using XAML ?

For a simple property I'm using a code looking like this :

```
var binding = new Binding("mySourceProperty");
binding.Source = mySourceObject;
myTargetObject.SetBinding(myTargetProperty, binding);
```

Where `myTargetProperty` can be, for example, `Shape.StrokeProperty`.
But now, how can I do the same thing on the `ColorProperty` of the `Stroke` of a `Shape` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that the Shape's `Stroke` property holds a SolidColorBrush, you can use the static `BindingOperations.SetBinding` method:

```
var shape = new Path(); // or whatever
var binding = new Binding { Source = Colors.Red }; // or whatever
BindingOperations.SetBinding(shape.Stroke, SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Thank you, the `BindingOperations.SetBinding()` was just what I was missing.